# Reduce time complexity when finding pairs in Java

Tags: java, arrays

To find pairs, usually using method is iterate through two loops that is,

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
```

It takes O(n^2) time complexity, is there any other method in Java to find pairs in lesser time complexity?

Comment: Probably. First, what defines a **pair**?

Comment: In an array, to find all  possible pairs of elements. For example, arr={1, 2,3} pairs are (1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3)..

Comment: That doesn't seem like something you're likely to need to do often; can we get more context? `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).forEach(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).forEach(y -> System.out.printf("%d, %d%n", x, y)));`

Comment: That seems like the very _definition_ of an `O(n^2)` problem.  Is there a less-than-obvious `O(n log n)` (I'd never dare hope for `O(n)`!) solution I've missed?

Comment: Thanks for the code, it is helpful. But I need to take an array, not a range from 1 to 3 or something. For example, consider this array a={8, 3,6,9}. we can't give a range right?

Comment: You should be able to stream an array with `IntStream.of(a)`.  But, using streams rather than `for`-loops doesn't _change_ the time complexity, it just **hides** it a little bit.  The only way to actually improve the time complexity would be with a **better algorithm**, assuming such an algorithm even exists.

Comment: Thank you Elliott Frisch and Kevin Anderson for your answers. I am a newbie in problem solving so whenever I try to solve a problem that includes pairs, it gives time complexity error. I need to improve my problem solving skills. You are right. Obviously this problem takes O(n^2).

Comment: What is the problem you are solving?

Comment: @iota To find number of pairs in an array, such that A[i]+A[j]=A[i]/A[j].

Comment: I can only think of one pair of numbers _a, b: a+b = a/b_, and that's _a=1/2, b=1/2_. It's so obvious it must be wrong.  But if true, you just need to count the number _n_ of 0.5s and then compute the number of ways of taking 2 objects at a time from a set of _n_ objects (_n! / (2!(n-2)!)_, or _(n(n-1)/2_, if I'm not mistaken...)

Answer (score 2):

According to your comments, what you are actually doing is generating all pair-wise combinations of the elements of a list as a list of pairs.

For a list of length `N`, there will be `N^2` pairs in the result list you want to generate.  But you cannot *construct* a list of `N^2` values in better than `O(N^2)`.  No matter what algorithm you use.  A list of `N^2` values has `N^2` cells that need to be assigned to ... which means that there are (at least) `N^2` primitive assignment operations to perform.

In short, what you are looking for is a mathematical impossibility.

Comment: Yeah now I understand Stephen C. I need to optimize my solution.

Comment: Yea.  To get better than `O(N^2)` performance, you need to remove the *need* to generate a list of `O(N^2)` elements.